# Using flexbox, image overflow throughout container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How to make my imgs not to overflow outside its container `<div class="display">` and perfectly make a square/box?

It should've work for flexbox.

As you can see, this snippets resulting 3 images with 1 outside which not properly a box.

```css
.display {
  min-width: 500px;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.scenery {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.scenery_1 {
  display: flex;
}

.scenery_2 {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="display">
<div class="scenery">
  <div class="scenery_1">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/02/e1/52/02e1528600a592817fbfa1c67158c13f.jpg" alt="display">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/02/e1/52/02e1528600a592817fbfa1c67158c13f.jpg" alt="display">
  </div>
  <div class="scenery_2">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/02/e1/52/02e1528600a592817fbfa1c67158c13f.jpg" alt="display">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/02/e1/52/02e1528600a592817fbfa1c67158c13f.jpg" alt="display">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/02/e1/52/02e1528600a592817fbfa1c67158c13f.jpg" alt="display">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: working fine here, whats the real issue?

Comment: don't you see the snippets?

Comment: yea, I've put a red border in `display` and all images fit inside

Comment: there are 5 images, which 2 in first row and 3 in second row.
I want to compress them to a box shape.

Comment: what?! I run the code but its not.

Comment: they are rectangles, use box shape images instead for that.

Comment: can you please write your answer?

Comment: but I want it responsivelly.

Comment: I got alot of images with different shape.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0d3zfnxt/

Comment: nope, it still overflowed. what browser did you use?

Comment: I use Firefox..

Comment: lol, I use chrome, why the hell it didn't work for chrome :(

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/D0urHkt.png

Comment: can you try it in chrome?
or Microsoft Edge?

Comment: it *is* overflowing in Chrome, can confirm

Comment: hm, so what to do now?
any fixes?

Comment: I've posted a fix, see if it checks out. :)

Comment: There seem to be two issues you want to resolve: (1) the overflow, and (2) the aspect ratio. The overflow solution is simple: Add `min-width: 0` to each `img`, and `min-height: 0` to their parent containers. https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using `display: flex`, but this works:

```css
.display {
  min-width: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block; /* Add this, remove everything else*/
}
```

```html
<div class="display">
  <div class="scenery">
    <div class="scenery_1">
      <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/02/e1/52/02e1528600a592817fbfa1c67158c13f.jpg" alt="display">
      <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/02/e1/52/02e1528600a592817fbfa1c67158c13f.jpg" alt="display">
    </div>
    <div class="scenery_2">
      <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/02/e1/52/02e1528600a592817fbfa1c67158c13f.jpg" alt="display">
      <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/02/e1/52/02e1528600a592817fbfa1c67158c13f.jpg" alt="display">
      <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/02/e1/52/02e1528600a592817fbfa1c67158c13f.jpg" alt="display">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: lol flexbox is more professional. but anyway thanks. I won't use any other else that don't use flexbox tho. :(

Comment: It works but... As the title say "Flexbox" lol, anyway thanks. just going to use background-image instead.

Comment: I can't do that right at this time. Doesn't have enough reputation to vote :(